# What are the reduction rules for value sets.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic

A value set is the vs function applied to a set of values, tagged with conditions for their truth. vs is defined by,
$$ v :: c \in S \wedge c \implies vs(S) = v $$

For ease of reading,
$\text{vs}\{v_1::c_1, ... v_n::c_n\}$ may be written $[v_1::c_1, ... v_n::c_n]$.

For example, $[2:: x_1, -2 ::x_2]$ is an expression that satisfies $x^2 = 4$.

The general formula for applying a function to a value set is.
$$ f(vs(S), vs(T)) = vs(\{f(s_v, s_v)::t_c \wedge t_c | s_v::s_c \in S \wedge  t_v::t_c \in T\}) $$

In general, a value set condition is a conjunction of conditions.

What are the reduction rules for value sets. How do we determine when conditions are proved false?

---

**Conditionless value sets**

For convenience, it is useful to write a value set without conditions. For example,
$ [2, -2] + [2, -2] = [4, 0, -4]$

But then,
$ x = [2, -2] $
would lead to a contradiction,

$ 2x = [4, -4] = x + x = [2, -2] + [2, -2] = [4, 0, -4]$

This type of contradition can only arise when a conditionless value set is asserted equal to a variable. Without the variable, it is impossible to copy the value set, to construct the contradiction.

By convention, when a value set is assigned to a variable, conditions are added, using the variable.

$ x = [2, -2] $ is taken to mean $x = [2::x=2, -2::x=-2]  = [2::x_1, -2::x_2]$.

Then,
$$ 2x = [4::::x_1, -4::x_2] = x + x = [2::x_1, -2::x_2] + [2::x_1, -2::x_2] = [4::x_1, -4::x_2]$$

which avoids the contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

**Reduction rule 1.**

Values in value sets must be consistent with the assertions. Conditions for values that give a falsehood are false.

Example.

Assert,
$[5::x_1, 8::x_2] + 5 = 10 $

Then $x2$ is false.

Proof: Obvious.

**Reduction rule 2**

If $x_1 ... x_n$ are the conditions of value set. 
$$ x_n \wedge x_n = x_n $$
$$ n \ne m \implies x_n \wedge x_m = \text{false} $$

Proof.
For value sets constructed from a variable, each condition is of the form $x_j = x = v_j$ where no two $v_j$ are the same. So $x_n \wedge x_m = (x=v_n) \wedge (x=v_m)$. As each value $v_j$ is distinct, this is false if $n \ne m$.

For variables constructed from functions on value sets, proof by induction.

**Reduction rule 3**

If a value set is the result of a calculation from parameter value sets, then every condition from those value sets is a conjunction of conditions. A condition present in the parameter value sets, but not in any of the conjunctions of conditions for the result's value set is false.

Proof: Hint. One of the conditions in the result's valuesets must be true.

There are no other reduction rules. Proof?

**Example**

$$ x = [5::x1, 10::x2]$$
$$ y = [6::y1, 11::y2]$$
$$ x  y = z $$
$$ z < 40 $$

**Calculation**

$$ z = [30::x1 \wedge y1, 50::x2 \wedge y1, 55::x1 \wedge y2, 110::x2 \wedge y2]$$
But $z < 40$ 
$$  z = [30::x1 \wedge y1]$$ Reduction rule 1.

$x_2$ and $y_2$ are false. Reduction rule 2.